# Datalist displayed like a table

Tags: html, css, xhtml, semantic-markup

How can i achieve this layout[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1870/screenshot20091212at151.jpg](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1870/screenshot20091212at151.jpg) (now its done with tables) and still have semantic markup, i guess the best suited tag for this would be dl. Every cell must have the height of their row.

EDIT: the left column contains the description and the right the data. So i don't think this is well suited for tables. It would be if i would move the description to the table head, but that would take 2000 px width

Comment: Whats wrong with using a table? Looks like table data to me :)

Comment: The correct declination of "lang" in this case would be "lange" :)

Comment: I can understand your concern somehow but have you never created a table in your favorite spreadsheet application with headers on the left side? Btw. the HTML DL tag stands for `definition list` not `data list`. And in my opinion a definition is something more or less static. But your data varies from user to user. But that is more semantic philosophy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the semantic and think that this is the reason why a definition list is better suited, read this [official document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) about definition list.

It says:

> Definition lists, created using the DL element, generally consist of a series of term/definition pairs (although definition lists may have other applications)

and

> Definition lists vary only slightly from other types of lists in that list items consist of two parts: a term and a description.

That means the term (e.g. `Anrede`) is described/defined by its description (e.g. `Herr`
). We can argue here, but `Herr` is not really a description of `Anrede` it is more one possible value/word (data) you can use as 
`Anrede`. And a definition would be

> A way to address persons, depending on gender, graduation etc.

Btw for all non german speakers, Anrede means salutation.

Of course there are exceptions but from an semantic point of view, a table fits better.

---

All I want to say is: Don't burden yourself with such things. To get this looking the same with DL tags and CSS is not worth the effort. To use a table for your data is fine, really.

Answer (score 1):

If it's tabular information, then a table is not the best, it's the **only** sensible way to display it - that's what tables were made for!

To be a bit more formal about it, the semantics of your data is indeed tabular, there's no reason in the world to lie about it.

Comment: The highly annoying CSS purist zealot crowd has struck so much fear of tables into peoples' hearts that now they're hesitant to use them even for tabular data! *grumble*

Comment: no not at all, maybe i wasn't clear enought explained: the left column contains the description and the right the data. So i don't think this is well suited for tables. It would be if i would move the description to the table head, but that would take 2000 px width

Comment: A table with headers is still a table. There are column headers and row headers; your descriptions are row headers. I still think you're seeing a problem that isn't.

Comment: It's beginning to look more and more like a Definition List to me. Not a *perfect* DL, but if you squint just a bit ...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `<dl>`, because it is just 2 columns.

Comment: yes that's where the problem begins! Every cell must have the height of their row.

Comment: I was going to protest, because a "standard" DL layout has the items on the next line from the headers, and sometimes overlapping. But of course CSS allows you to fix up the format to look nice.